# Could I get some help understating what is causing my "NoSuchElementException"?

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am currently going through the Helsinki MOOC for Java OOP and I have hit a snag on one of the questions.  I am working on [Week 7 Exercise 8](https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part2/week-7/) and when I run my code manually I am getting everything to work out okay.  However when I run their automated tests I am getting the "NoSuchElementException" error.

It is my understanding from the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) on this particular error that it is most likely caused by .nextLine() not finding a line to read.  What confuses me though is based on the error message, and the location of the exceptions, my use of .nextLine() is working in some places and not others while I am using it in the same manner. I included my class that I am using below.  Thanks for the help everyone, and if I overlooked a previous post similar to this I apologize.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AirportPanel {
    private Scanner reader;
    private ArrayList<Airplane> airplanes;
    private ArrayList<Flight> flights;

    public AirportPanel(Scanner reader){
        this.reader = reader;
        this.airplanes = new ArrayList<Airplane>();
        this.flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    }

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Airport panel");
        System.out.println("--------------------\n");

        while(true){
            printMenu();
            String input = readString();
            if(input.toLowerCase().equals("x")){
                break;
            }else{
                chooseOperation(input);
            }
        }
    }

    private void printMenu(){
        System.out.println("Choose operation:");
        System.out.println("[1] Add airplane" + "\n[2] Add flight" + "\n[x]                 Exit");
        System.out.print("> ");        
    }

    private void chooseOperation(String input){
        if(input.equals("1")){
            addPlane();
        }else{
            addFlight();
        }
    }

    private void addPlane(){
        System.out.print("Give plane ID: ");
        String planeID = readString();
        System.out.print("Give plane capacity: ");
        String planeCap = readString();

        this.airplanes.add(new Airplane(planeID, planeCap));
    }

    private void addFlight(){
        System.out.print("Give plane ID: ");
        String planeID = readString();
        System.out.print("Give departure airport code: ");
        String airport1 = readString();
        System.out.print("Give destination airport code: ");
        String airport2 = readString();

        String airports = airport1 + "-" + airport2;

        for(Airplane ap : this.airplanes){
            if(ap.getID().equals(planeID)){
                this.flights.add(new Flight(ap, airports));
            }
        }
    }

    private String readString(){
        return this.reader.nextLine();
    }
```

**EDIT:** [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh6W3.jpg) is a screenshot of the stack trace. I [also made a github repo](https://github.com/Hooper2993/Java-MOOC-Week-7-Exercise-8.git) with all of my files in the event that would help more.  I am pretty new to coding so excuse the mess I surely made of these files.

**EDIT 2:** I went to my readString() method and changed my call of .nextLine() to .next() and it fixed my issue.  I'm not entirely sure how or why but it is now submitting correctly.

Comment: From `Scanner#nextLine()`: *throws java.util.NoSuchElementException – if no line was found*. So in the automated tests you try to read a line even if there is none

Comment: Right, but my question I suppose is, where is that occurring in the above code? I can't exactly pinpoint where or why?

Comment: Probably in the `readString()` method, as it's the only place where you call `reader.nextLine()`

Comment: I go on to call that readString() method throughout the class so I wasn't sure if the issue was in the method itself or one of the call.  I tried to figure that out by just going ahead and cutting the contents of readString() and using them in place of the method call.  I still got the exception when checking it with the automated tests.

Comment: Please add your test code and full stack trace.